# Is there a way to open a file with app-specific extension on Android 11 without MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm trying to update my app to target Android 11 (30). The app allows users to save and open files in specific format with extensions like `.cave`, `.svx`, `.th` - these are basically text formats.
For now, I was using https://github.com/isabsent/FilePicker to search through the file tree, but after permissions change, I'm no longer able to see desired files on the list without granting MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. Updated manifest was rejected by Google Play as violating the new policy with **Not a core feature** label.

I've tried to replace the file picker with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("text/plain");
```

but then the desired files are gray-out and I'm not able to select any of them. Also, in this example, the `DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI` parameter seems to be ignored - the build-in picker always starts from `Recent files` folder.

Is there a different solution to open the file with an unusual extension?

Comment: Use `*/*` for the MIME type, to allow all MIME types.

Comment: Or `"text/*"` And INITIAL_URI does work.

Comment: setting type to `*/*` did work, but the `INITIAL_URI` is still ignored

Comment: No you can use INITIAL_URI. And should do it in the right way of course.